# Modification of compact complex manifold

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Is a modification (holomorphic and bimeromerphic) of a compact quotient of the polydisk Kähler?

Comment: A compact quotient of the polydisk in Kähler (since the Bergman metric descends from the polydisk). Now, a modification of a compact Kähler manifold may not necessarily be Kähler without further assumptions, cf Hironaka's counter-example and the discussion in the introduction there https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jdg/1214453424 .

Comment: PS: In the example here, compact quotients of the polydisk are even projective (since their canonical bundle is ample), but so is Hironaka's counter-example.

Comment: Okay thank you so much for the answer